# Lazy loading routes on startup in angular application based on tenant(domain hostname)

Tags: angular, angular8

I need to have separate routes in an Angular application on startup based on the hostname. For that, I created a separate service TenantService to obtain the tenant. Next, I created another service called AppRoutingService that has a function to create routes based on the response for TenantService. This function needs to be executed on startup of the application and edit the app routes accordingly.

Following is the error I received and next up are the code snippets:

```
Getting cyclic dep error
compiler.js:10477 Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1
    at NgModuleProviderAnalyzer.parse (compiler.js:10477)
    at NgModuleCompiler.compile (compiler.js:20607)
    at JitCompiler._compileModule (compiler.js:25606)
    at compiler.js:25567
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25565)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:25527)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:216)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ (core.js:34647)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:34956)
```

Here is the code:

**AppModule**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TenantService } from './tenant/tenant.service';
import {AppRoutingService} from './app-routing.service';

export function initSettings(appRoutingService: AppRoutingService) {
  return () => appRoutingService.initializeRoutes();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  providers: [TenantService,
    AppRoutingService,
  {
    provide : APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory : initSettings,
    deps : [AppRoutingService],
    multi : true
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**AppRoutingService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {TenantService, Tenant } from './tenant/tenant.service';
import { Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { from } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppRoutingService {

  constructor(private router: Router, private tenantService: TenantService) { }

  initializeRoutes(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let appRoutes: Routes = [];
      if (this.tenantService.getTenant() === Tenant.CLIENT1) {
        console.log('Configuring CLIENT1 Login Components.');
        appRoutes = [
          { path: 'hotel-list', loadChildren: () => import('./hotel/hotel.module').then(m => m.HotelModule) },
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'hotel-list', pathMatch: 'full'}
        ];
        appRoutes.forEach(e => this.router.config.unshift(e));
        resolve(true);
      } else if (this.tenantService.getTenant() === Tenant.CLIENT2) {
        console.log('Configuring CLIENT2 Login Components.');
        appRoutes = [
          { path: 'natgeo-list', loadChildren: () => import('./natgeo/natgeo.module').then(m => m.NatgeoModule) },
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'natgeo-list', pathMatch: 'full'}
        ];
        appRoutes.forEach(e => this.router.config.unshift(e));
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        reject(false);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**TenantService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TenantService {
  constructor() {}

  getTenantForHostname(hostname: string): Tenant {
    return this.getTenantForHost(hostname.split('.')[0]);    
  }

  getTenantForString(s: string) {
    for (const e in Tenant) {
      if (e.toLowerCase() === s.toLowerCase()) {
        return Tenant[e] as Tenant;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  getTenantForHost(host: string): Tenant {
    return this.getTenantForString(host);
  }

  getTenant(): Tenant {
    return this.getTenantForHostname(location.hostname);
  }

  addTenantToHeaders(headers: HttpHeaders): HttpHeaders {
    return headers.append('X-Tenant-ID', this.getTenant());
  }
}

export enum Tenant {
  CLIENT1 = 'hotel',
  CLIENT2 = 'natgeo'
}
```

Any help towards rectifying the error is appreciated. Also, an alternate approach to satisfy my requirements is also welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Injector` to get the `Router` and reset it.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/github/hsuanxyz/ng-dynamic-routes-config

Github Repo https://github.com/hsuanxyz/ng-dynamic-routes-config

**tenant.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TenantService {

  getTenant() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TenantService } from './tenant.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export function initSettings(injector: Injector, tenantService: TenantService) {
  return () => new Promise(resolve => {
    let routes = [];
    if (tenantService.getTenant()) {
      routes = [
        { path: 'hotel-list', loadChildren: () => import('./hotel/hotel.module').then(m => m.HotelModule) },
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'hotel-list', pathMatch: 'full' }
      ];
    } else {
      routes = [
        { path: 'natgeo-list', loadChildren: () => import('./natgeo/natgeo.module').then(m => m.NatgeoModule) },
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'natgeo-list', pathMatch: 'full' }
      ];
    }
    const router: Router = injector.get(Router);
    router.resetConfig(routes);
    resolve();
  });
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    TenantService,
    {
      provide : APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory : initSettings,
      deps : [Injector, TenantService],
      multi : true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```